# Example of function definition in the data constructor of a new type

Tags: haskell, types, pattern-matching

We can use type synonym for function definitions, e.g.

```
type FuncDef = Int -> Int -> Int
```

This avoids us writing long function definition every time.

Use:

```
someFunc :: FuncDef -> Int
```

Instead of

```
someFunc :: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Int
```

which is more readable and less code as well.

Simple algebraic data types are straight forward and easy to do pattern matching etc, e.g.

```
data AType = X | Y | Z Int
matchType :: AType -> Bool
matchType X = ..
matchType Y = ..
matchType (Z _) = ..
```

As I look more into Haskell data types, I found we can have function definition in data constructor when defining new type.

```
data MyType a b = X | Y (a -> b)
```

This puzzles me a bit and haven't seen many examples of this around. In a way, the idea of high-order function where a function can take another function as argument is similar to this situation, except here it applies to data type. The Haskell wiki does not say much about "high-order data type definition". I realise I may be getting all these terms wrong, so please correct me, and point me to more reading. I really want to see a concrete usage of this. Thanks!

```
matchMyType :: (MyType a b) -> Bool
matchMyType X = ..
matchMyType Y ?? = ..
```

Comment: I think you may just be worrying too much! Like you say, functions can be passed as arguments. That's because functions aren't inherently different from any other value. You can put them in a data type and extract them by pattern matching. That's really all there is to it.

Comment: thanks +1, it absolutely makes sense what you said. can you give me an example where i would want to put a function in a data structure instead of just values e.g. integers in a tree?

Comment: Well, most practical uses I can think of for data types containing functions are more complicated and would probably just distract from the issue. If you want a generic example, dave4420's answer will do fine. If you want something more challenging to ponder, the obligatory example is probably the [state monad transformer](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#g:2).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might use this kind of pattern in many situations. For example, if you want a function that transforms strings in various ways, you might have a data type like this (This is just an example that demonstrates the principle - don't write code like this!):

```
data StringTransformation =
  -- | Doesn't transform the string at all
  NoTransformation |
  -- | Takes the string and generates a suffix that should be appended
  Append (String -> String) |
  -- | Takes the string and generates a prefix that should be prepended
  Prepend (String -> String) |
  -- | Takes the string and transforms it arbitrarily to a new string
  Map (String -> String)
```

Then, a program that uses this might look like:

```
-- | Returns 'True' if the name is male
isMaleName :: String -> Bool
isMaleName = ...

-- | Adds a title to a name, for example "John Smith" -> "Mr. John Smith"
addTitle :: StringTransformation
addTitle =
  PrependTransformation $ \ name ->
  if isMaleName name
  then "Mr. "
  else "Mrs. "

-- Applies a string transformation to a 'String'.
transformString :: StringTransformation -> String -> String
transformString NoTransformation str = str
transformString (Append f) str       = str ++ f str
transformString (Prepend f) str      = f str ++ str
transformString (Map f) str          = f str
```

Comment: +1 nice example :) will accept answer if i don't get any other.

Answer (score 4):

```
data Thingy a b = A b
                | B (a -> b)

really :: Thingy a b -> a -> b
really (A x) _ = x              -- x :: b
really (B f) y = f y            -- f :: a -> b, y :: a, f y :: b
```

As C.A.McCann says, there's nothing special about functions really.

Comment: thanks. i think the order of the arguments in the pattern matching is not right. i do see how to do pattern matching on the function in the data type, similar to any normal high-order function. why store a function in the type? :s